# In Nodejs how to irritate array object to get desire response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, key-value

In Nodejs in getting array object , how to irritate it to get desire response?
objects can b multiples.

Following response im getting through  MYSQL query.

```
   let data = [
   {
    id: 'f08d',
     tack: 0,
      pro: 0,
     conn: 12
  }
  ]
```

here is required response:

```
Desired response:
  ids:{ f08d, f08d,f08d },
   name:{tack,pro,conn },
 count:{ 0,0, 12 }
```

How i can get the above result?

using key/value

```
     let details= {};
        details.ids = [];
        details.name= [];
        details.count = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < Object.entries(data ).length; i++) {

   for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data [i])) {
          
          ///  do something here like this
         details.count.push(value);
           details.name.push(key);
            details.ids.push(id);
         

         }  

     }
         retrun details;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I modified your code to create your desired data object.

```
let data = [
  {
    id: "f08d",
    tack: 0,
    pro: 0,
    conn: 12,
  },
  {
    id: "f09d",
    tack: 1,
    pro: 1,
    conn: 13,
    comm: 15
  }
];
console.log(data);
let details = {};
details.ids = [];
details.name = [];
details.count = [];

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data[i])) {
    ///  do something here like this
    if (key !== "id") {
      details.count.push(value);
      details.name.push(key);
    }
  }
  // length-1 to exclude id from other attributes
  for (let j = 0; j < Object.entries(data[i]).length-1; j++) {
    details.ids.push(data[i].id);
  }
}
console.log(details);
```

Comment: thanks Umar for reply, but when there is multiple object , for 2nd object it will add 6 time ids instead of  3  times.

Comment: Okay! I updated my answer. I hope it will work now